# Why wont my Mysql event run

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I have an Event created on mysql.

I have an event but does not run at 01:00:00 .If i change the time to 14:00:00 or any other time it works fine.I changed the time from 14:00:00 it ran fine,but did not re -run after 12 hours as scheduled.This is the code

```
           DELIMITER //
          CREATE EVENT trending_calculation
          ON SCHEDULE EVERY 12 HOUR
          STARTS '2014-09-27 01:00:00'
          DO
          BEGIN
          call business_trending1;
          call business_trending2;
          call business_trending_update3;
          call business_trending4;
          call business_trending5;
          END;//
          Delimiter ;
```

Am i doing something wrong.
I have global event scheduler as ON.
Please advise and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was copying the code directly onto the command line from notepad and i guess some eof characters were being copied or something else.
The moment i saved the code as an sql file and ran that file it worked.